# how to get a value inside a child node without giving parent node in a xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, nodes, child-nodes, parent-node

I have a xml that looks like this

```
<req>
  <info>
  <element name = "bob" value="20"/>
  <element name = "reena" value="50"/>
  </info>
</req>
```

I need to get value 20 or 50 without using parent nodes req and info

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find something like

```
number(//element[@name="reena"]/@value)
```

a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
number(//element[1]/@value)
```

This navigates directly to your first element and returns the attribute value it finds.